# How do I create one single file choose button with PrimeNG?

Tags: html, angular, forms, file-upload, primeng

I am creating a form that contains three fields: file name, file description, and the file itself. **I want to create a PrimeNG-style button that can open file picker and let users choose a file.** After choosing file, my application will use the information of the file to update the name field. Eventually, when description is filled in, users can hit the submit button which calls onSubmit that parses the file and sends some information to a server.

What I want is a single button that:

1. Is PrimeNG styled
2. Has no borders or anything other than the button itself
3. Won't turn into an upload button like it does with p-fileUpload's basic mode
4. Will indicate when a file is chosen

What I have tried:

```
<p-fileUpload chooseLabel="Choose" name="xmls[]" [showUploadButton]="false" [showCancelButton]="false" [multiple]="false" accept=".arxml" (onSelect)="onSelect($event)">
</p-fileUpload>
```

This will create a choose button, but it also comes with a box that I don't want. I have also tried the basic mode, but the choose button will turn into an upload button once a file is chosen. I want to have a separated submit button that will submit name, description, and the file.

Any help is appreciated.